# OneToOne Joining to Self

Tags: typeorm

Is it possible to join an entity to itself using a OneTonOne relationship?

I tried this:

```
@OneToOne(type => Person, spouse => spouse.id)
@JoinColumn()
spouse: Person;
```

But get this error from code that otherwise worked:

```
{ QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/jonhaven/Dev/Maverick/mav-typeorm/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:7:9)
    at Statement.handler (/Users/jonhaven/Dev/Maverick/mav-typeorm/src/driver/sqlite/SqliteQueryRunner.ts:53:26)
    at Statement.replacement (/Users/jonhaven/Dev/Maverick/mav-typeorm/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.replacement (/Users/jonhaven/Dev/Maverick/mav-typeorm/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31)
  message: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed',
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
  name: 'QueryFailedError',
  query: 'DROP TABLE "person"',
  parameters: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of SQLite on TypeORM. You should update TypeORM to latest version, and add delete cascade option in relationship

```js
@OneToOne(type => Person, spouse => spouse.id, { 
  cascade: true, 
  onDelete: "CASCADE" 
})
@JoinColumn()
spouse: Person;
```